# Is it possible to get the position of a Chrome packaged app window in realtime

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I know there is onBoundsChanged, but that only returns the current position once you have stopped dragging the window. Is there a way to return the current position while you are dragging the window?

The reason I'm wanting to do this is so I can have two windows snapped to each other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [windows](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/windows) sample app? That has an example of two windows that stick together, using `onBoundsChanged` to set the bounds of the window.

```
originalWindow.onBoundsChanged.addListener(function() {
      var bounds = originalWindow.outerBounds;
      copycatWindow.outerBounds.left = bounds.left + bounds.width + 5;
    });
```

Also, that sample uses `webkitRequestAnimationFrame` to display the window's position information in real time.

```
function update() {
    ['screenX', 'screenY', 'innerWidth', 'innerHeight'].forEach(function(prop) {
        document.getElementById(prop).innerText = window[prop];
    });

    webkitRequestAnimationFrame(update);
}

update();
```

Comment: This seems to work in realtime, at least in Linux. But this can vary from platform to platform, in theory.

Comment: Just tested this out on mac and it doesn't seem to update in realtime. I guess this is os specific?

Comment: Looks like it. On Windows it works in realtime and on Chrome OS it works in realtime but with a strong flicker.